# Can I use Rikulo in a section of a HTML page and in Portal?

Tags: liferay, portal, dart, rikulo

It is possible to use Rikulo in a section of a HTML page rather than taking the whole space as shown in the Hello World sample? Furthermore, can I use it as a portlet in, say, Liferay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is to assign id that matches the containerId argument of Activity.run(). By default, it is v-main. For example,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/css/view.css" />
...
<div>Foo Header</div>
....
<div id="v-main" style="width:300px;height:200px"></div>
...
<script type="application/dart" src="Foo.dart"></script>
<script src="../../resources/js/dart.js"></script>
```

For more information, please refer to [Embed in HTML Page](http://docs.rikulo.org/rikulo/latest/Views/Fundamentals/Embed_in_HTML_Page.html).

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically, calling View#addToDocument and passing the DOM node you wanted this View to attach to as the first argument would also help.

See also:
https://github.com/rikulo/rikulo/blob/master/client/view/src/View.dart#L476